# LNK4006 error in XLW 4.0.0.f0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

[XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) is an open sourced library that wrap C++ code into XLL add-in for Excel.  A strange LNK4006 error is reported in a project i'm handling, reporting an XLW function is "already defined".

I'm using XLW [version 4.0.0.f0](https://sourceforge.net/p/xlw/code/HEAD/tree/tags/R040000f0), to simplify the situation, I break down it to a toy project, there are only three files --

StdAfx.cpp, the boilterplate file :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

StdAfx.h, boilterplate but mysterious (I never understood the content)

```
#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__0D719468_50D1_11D2_9DAF_00207813663F__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H_0_D719468_50D1_11D2_9DAF_00207813663F__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER >= 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1000

#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>         // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT


//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Developer Studio will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__0D719468_50D1_11D2_9DAF_00207813663F__INCLUDED_)
```

and then the puzzle, WhyLNK4006.cpp:

```
#include <xlw/xlw.h> 
void WhyLNK4006()
{
    xlw::XlfExcel &x = xlw::XlfExcel::Instance();
    xlw::XlfExcel::Instance().FreeMemory(); 
}
```

This will trigger an LNK4006 error, which I could suppress it as a warning but couldn't guess why this happen:

> xlw-vc120-mt-gd-4_0_0f0.lib(XlfExcel.obj) : warning LNK4006: "public:
>   void __thiscall xlw::XlfExcel::FreeMemory(bool)"
>   (?FreeMemory@XlfExcel@xlw@@QAEX_N@Z) already defined in B15.obj;
>   second definition ignored

I couldn't understand, why there's such an error?

Both XLW and my toy project are compiled as `/MTd`, all XLW header file XXX.h have preprocessor protection e.g.

```
> #if !defined(XXX_H)
> #define XXX_H //the read content of XXX.h
> #endif
```

How come this could lead to a double definition?

Comment: Is Xlw is static lib?

Comment: @Matt I compiled it as static library .

Comment: Do you also include the CPP file which contains the implementation of XlfExcel::FreeMemory? if you do, that is the reason.

Comment: @Matt no I didn't. All codes are as above